# Can a simple curve intersect every subspace of dim 2 and avoid the origin?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, real-analysis

Is there, e.g. in $\mathbb R^4$ a simple curve that does not contain the origin and intersects every subspace of dimension 2?

Sorry if the question is too easy, but I just cannot figure it out.
In three dimensions such a curve exists, but I cannot imagine four dimensions. Is it possible to somehow lift-up the Peano-curve? What about higher dimensions and higher dimensional subspaces?

Comment: It is equivalent to ask for a curve in $\Bbb R^3$ that intersects every vector line.

Comment: A Peano-curve type construction does intersect every line through the origin, so I suppose then the answer to my original question is yes. But what about five dimensions then?

Comment: Hm, even this works in any dimension, oh well...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider closed space filling curve $\theta:\mathbb S^1\to\mathbb S^3$.
You can choose $\theta$ so that $\theta^{-1}(x)$ is finite for any $x\in\mathbb S^3$
and $|\theta^{-1}(x)|=1$ for all but countable set in $\mathbb S^3$.

Then it is easy to find a function $\rho:\mathbb{S}^1\to\mathbb R_+$
so that the curve $\gamma(x)=(\theta(x),\rho(x)$ in polar coordinates 
is the curve you are looking for.

Comment: I see, and this of course works for every dimension. Thank you!